# @Transactional not working giving exception to add @Transactional

Tags: java, jpa, orm, annotations, playframework-2.2

I am using jpa with Play 2.2.1 java .I have a method which finds all the the jobseekers

My controller function

```
@Transactional
     public static Result index() {

        return ok(views.html.admin.jobseeker.render("Your new application is ready.", Jobseekers.all()));

    }
```

and model method

```
public static List<Jobseekers> all() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Jobseekers> el = JPA.em().createQuery("from Jobseekers order by id").getResultList();
        return el;
    }
```

But i am getting exception

```
[RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional]
```

I dont know why its giving this error even though I have added @Transactional

Can anybody help me??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct annotation is `@Transactional` not @Transaction

Comment: still getting same result

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct `@Transactional`?